# routerLink does not generate the link correctly

Tags: angular, angular-routing

This html button with routerLink attribute:

```
<button [routerLink]="['/projects', 'edit', project?.id]">E`enter code here`dit</button>
```

result in this link:

```
  router-link="/projects,edit,1011"
```

I can not see from the documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html

that I do something wrong.

This sample looks nearly like mine:

```
['/team', teamId, 'user', userName, {details: true}]
```

what do I wrong?

Comment: Try changing `button` to `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can associated code with a button click and *then* route with a method such as this:

```
onSaveComplete(message?: string): void {
    if (message) {
        this.messageService.addMessage(message);
    }
    this.reset();
    // Navigate back to the product list
    this.router.navigate(['/products']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the routerLink needs to be on a link element. Such as this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" 
  [routerLink]="['/productEdit', product.id]">
  Edit
</a>
```

Comment: ok bad... I need to bind the disable attribute, then I have to use the <button> with a (click)="edit(project.id) event :-/

Comment: So you need a button that routes and then also has code to run on the click event? If so, then add the routing in code in the click event's associated method.

Comment: No extra code to run via click event, BUT the disable attribute does not work on <a>-tag just on <button>.

Answer (score 0):

RouterLink' input is an array of strings, so in html:

```
<button [routerLink]="routerLink">My button</button>
```

TS:

```
routerLink = project.id ? ['/projects', 'edit', project.id] : ['/projects', 'edit']
```